# how to migrate snapshot.data.data(); to null safety

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

this is the code can any help me how to change this to null safety, I am getting errors in .data(). i changed my project to null-safety, and then i am facing this issue

this is the error

The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

`Map<String, dynamic>? documentData = snapshot.data.data();`

```
class HomeSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? doc_id;
  HomeSlider({this.doc_id});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<HomeSlider> {
  FirebaseServices _firebaseServices = FirebaseServices();
  int activeIndex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
        // height: 200,
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _firebaseServices.sliderRef
                .doc(widget.doc_id == null ? "Slider" : widget.doc_id)
                .get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                );
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

                     // the error is here in data()
                // Firebase Document Data Map
                Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data.data();

                List? imageList = documentData['images'];
                List? suid = documentData['suid'];

                return SliderBody(
                  imageList: imageList,
                  suid: suid,
                );
              }
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }));
  }}
```

Comment: try snapshot.data!.data()

Comment: nope. didn't work. do you have any other idea?

Comment: Could you provide some more code please, so we can understand where the error is coming from, what is data() for example and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i have added the entire code

Comment: when you did  snapshot.data!.data() , did you still have the same null safety error?

Comment: yeah that was the same error

Comment: yeah i was facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you should go with

```
Map<String, dynamic>? documentData = snapshot!.data.data();
```

Comment: no. that is not working. i still have that problem

Comment: what about snapshot!.data!.data();

Comment: nope, still facing the same error

Comment: i also added the entire code, you can take a look

Comment: can you try once  
final data = snapshot.data; 
Map<String, dynamic> documentData  = data.data();

Comment: yeah still facing the same error

Comment: why null-safety is that much hard

Comment: after using above suggestion on which line its showing error? When assigning to data or when assigning to documentData?

Comment: no error is on data()

Comment: nothing has change with the above code

Comment: still facing error on .data()

Comment: now try documentData = data!.data(); or documentData = data?.data();

Comment: now i am facing this error

Comment: The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'

Comment: error is still with .data()

Comment: add your future function and model to your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in   `builder: (context, snapshot) {` after adding the `AsyncSnapshot` and finally like this.       `builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {`  and also add `!` before `.data()`

```
class HomeSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? doc_id;
  HomeSlider({this.doc_id});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<HomeSlider> {
  FirebaseServices _firebaseServices = FirebaseServices();
  int activeIndex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
        // height: 200,
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _firebaseServices.sliderRef
                .doc(widget.doc_id == null ? "Slider" : widget.doc_id)
                .get(),
            builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                );
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

                     // the error is here in data()
                // Firebase Document Data Map
                Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data!.data();

                List? imageList = documentData['images'];
                List? suid = documentData['suid'];

                return SliderBody(
                  imageList: imageList,
                  suid: suid,
                );
              }
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }));
  }}
```